# Trino iceberg connector "getTablesWithParameter for GlueHiveMetastore is not implemented"

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-emr, trino, apache-iceberg

I'm running trino on EMR version 6.5 and I have added the iceberg connector for the trino and I want it to use a glue catalog. These are the configuration under the iceberg.properties

```
connector.name=iceberg
iceberg.file-format=PARQUET
hive.metastore = glue
hive.metastore.glue.region = us-east-1
hive.metastore.glue.endpoint-url = https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I connect to the server via CLI or python client (trino-cli --catalog iceberg) I get the following error for any query (for example show tables)

> message="getTablesWithParameter for GlueHiveMetastore is not implemented"

Does anybody know if I have the wrong configuration or can guide me on the right direction?

Comment: EMR-6.5 doesn’t support Trino with Iceberg by default, you need to install v0.11 connector to make Trino work. I assume you’ve already did that and still it’s not working? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-iceberg-considerations.html

Answer (score 1):

Glue support was added in Trino version 374 and I was using the older version of Trino installed on EMR.

[Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/11831)